# Apply masterPage to SearchCenter on Subsite

Tags: wss-3.0, master-page, custom-masterpage, sub-site

I am working in a project in `Sharepoint Designer` that was already built in `MOSS 2007`, and it has the structure:

An site collection `/` and some subsites, one of them called `SearchCenter`.

The `SearchCenter` is where the sharepoint is redirected when you make search, but it has the default layout from iternal sites (it have its own masterpage defined in its folder) in sharepoint.
I would like to know how to apply one masterpage from the `catalogs/masterpages` to this subsite.